# the different usages of つもり?

Tags: grammar, words, formal-nouns

Hi all I understand that つもり means "intention" like say 夏休みにはゆっくり休むつもりです。 = I intend to rest during the summer vacation.

But what does 分かっているつもりだ。 means?

Well if I translate directly, it seems to be "I intend to be in the know" ?

However the translation (not by me) was "I know that."

I'm just wondering how did it work out to be that way? What is the significance of that つもり in that question?

Comment: Hum. I can't find many instances of your sentence.  I do find "分かったつもり", which means "I had the intention to understand" (but in fact, I did not understand a thing), but this is the opposite of the translation you gave. (Translation by whom, if I may?)

Comment: www.narutoget.com/watch/830-naruto-shippuden-episode-219-english-subbed/ at 1:54

Comment: Hum, let's do as if I already knew the sentence… I have no idea about the story, but maybe it's a nuance like "I (forcibly) acknowledge that"?

Comment: In my mind it means "That's what I figured", but I cannot explain why, so I'm not writing an answer.

Comment: alternative link: http://www.tailedfox.com/page-naruto-shippuden-219

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The translation 'intention' is not that bad, but maybe, 'have in mind' will work more generally.

> 夏休みにはゆっくり休むつもりです。
>
> I have in mind to take a full rest during the summer vacation.

In `分かっているつもりだ`, `つもり` is one way of making your statement accurate, and in many cases polite. In linguistic terms, this is called a *hedge*. In this particular case, everyone might think herself/himself is right, but they can actually never be sure about their knowledge. If you simply say

> I understand that ...,

then it might later, for some reason, turn out that you actually haven't understood it. In that case, you would be lying. But if, instead, you have said

> I think I understand that ...,

then your statement remains true. The latter statement is more accurate. And it is also polite in not saying a lie, and for being careful about your words. It is the same thing for Japanese sentences

> 分かっている 'I know that'

vs.

> 分かっているつもりだ 'What I have in mind is I know that' or 'I think I know that'

Comment: thx, btw what's the difference between this usage of つもり and と思う ?

Comment: つもり might have a slightly stronger degree of confidence than 思う.

Comment: @Pacerier: つもり = conviction: "I perfectly know that"

Comment: @Pacerier That is too strong.

Comment: The dictionary says "conviction/belief" so I don't think it is too strong.

Comment: @Pacerier, @sawa: The context is "someone needs to restore order to the hierarchy in the village (because the current leader is not available)". The character answers "分かっているつもりだ". He is perfectly aware of the situation with the current leader and he knows he is the favorite for the place of leader. "I'm aware of that", "I perfectly know that", are all correct translations. "I think I know that" is incorrect.

Comment: @repecmps So you are you a prescriptivist. Whose translation is that?

Comment: It's my translation. After looking at the context, "conviction/belief" makes perfect sense. I think it's a great example of descriptive linguistics. Look at the episode and tell me if the person saying 分かっているつもりだ is certain or uncertain.

Comment: @repecmps How can a translation made by a person who has 'native intuition' but needs to seek online dictionaries be a source of descriptive linguistics? I don't understand that.

Comment: Completely off-topic. My point is made above. To answer you: Linguists know that つもり has many meanings (I give you online sources because they are accessible to everyone). Now if they look at current practical uses (the context in our case) then it is descriptive linguistics (opposite of prescriptive). Do you have more off-topic questions or do you want to talk about つもり?

Comment: @sawa and @repecmps: first, I don't think either of your comments are necessarily off-topic (or deserve to be flagged). Second, while it is perfectly fine and healthy to start arguing your respective point, may I suggest using a chat room for that (SE will helpfully offer to relocate your long threads to one). For example, deleting all but your first comment each, and resuming your dialogue in the more appropriate setting of a chat, would be a great idea.

Comment: @repecmps: Who ever says "I perfectly know that..." in English? Maybe what you're looking for is "I'm perfectly aware that..." Thanks for helping my understanding of this less common usage

Comment: There are 500K results for "perfectly know" on google, but "I'm perfectly aware that" looks ok too.

Answer (score 9):

I am a Japanese woman living in Osaka.

The phrase "分かっているつもりだ" implies a situation like "no matter how you say that I don't know about it, I believe that I know it very well".

See?　If your girl friend said "hey, you don't know how I feel when you come home late!", then you can say "I have to work! But I know your feelings (分かっているつもりだ）".

Not only in a bad situations.

If you were a president of the US, you know the significance of your influence.
Then you can say "As for the significance of my speeches, I think I know that very well(分かっているつもりだ）."

See?

Answer (score 8):

OK, as a Japanese native, let me explain more about it.

As repecmps mentioned, つもり has several meanings and usage depending on the situation.
I would like to give you examples of usage of つもり, to show you the difference of nuance.

1. 明日学校に行くつもりだ。
   I will (intend to) go to school tomorrow.
2. a） あなたの気持ちはわかっているつもりだ。
   I believe I know your feelings well enough.

   b）この会社の経営状況はわかっているつもりだ。
   I believe I know the business performance and financial situations of this company.

   c) 科学については、あなたより私のほうがわかっているつもりだ。
   I am confident that I know about science more than you do.

1) is a simple statement of a fact or intention. In case of 2-a, b and c, the character is  somehow explaining him/herself, therefore often involve some kind of emotion, like the phrases below.

For example:

2a:

> 1. あなたの気持ちはわかっているつもりだ。だから私を信頼してほしい。
>      I believe I know your feelings well enough, so please trust me.
> 2. あなたの気持ちはわかっているつもりだ。でも私達は別れるしかない。
>      I believe I know your feelings well enough. But we have no choice other than breaking up.

2b:

> 1. この会社の経営状況はわかっているつもりだ。だから私が次のCEOにふさわしい。
>      I believe I know the business performance and financial situations of this company, so I think I am suitable for the next CEO of this company.
> 2. この会社の経営状況はわかっているつもりだ。だからこの投資は絶対利益になると確信している。
>      I believe I know the business performance and financial situations of this company, so I am perfectly positive that this investment will make an enormous benefit for us.

2c:

> 1. 科学については、あなたより私のほうがわかっているつもりだ。だから知ったかぶりはしないほうがいい。
>      I am confident that I know about science more 
>      than you do, so you'd better stop the know-it-all attitude.
> 2. 科学については、あなたより私のほうがわかっているつもりだ。でも日本の文化に関する知識については、あなたにはとてもかなわない。
>      I am confident that I know about science more than you do. But as for the knowledge of Japanese culture, I am no match to you.

Please forgive my poor English.
I hope this will answer your question.

Sincerely,

Comment: Cypher, thank you a lot, great explanation,it helped so much!

Answer (score 6):

つもり also marks conviction/belief

> つもり 《積もり(P); 積り》 (n) (1) (uk)
>   intention; plan; (2) conviction;
>   belief; (P)

I would say: "I perfectly know that" or "that's what I figured" are good translations for the following context:

"someone needs to restore order to the hierarchy in the village (because the current leader is not available)". The character answers "分かっているつもりだ". He is perfectly aware of the situation with the current leader and he knows he is the favorite for the place of leader.

Comment: Actually @Sawa may be correct from a native perspective. According to Goo 「つもりだ」 when not expressing the speaker's intention means「…と思っているらしい」「…と考えているそうだ」 and is used when discussing rumour or conjecture. Ref: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/17334/m0u/

Comment: @crunchyt: つもりだ has many meanings and they depends on the context. 1 meaning is conviction/belief and it fits perfectly the present context (which people need to look at before giving a guess) We're talking about facts, not rumor.

Comment: @crunchyt: After looking at the dictionary entry, I confirm that there is no incertitude in the sentence. Thus making "I think" incorrect. It looks more like つもり implies a conclusion based on an observation: "That's what I figured", "It looks like it is", "I guess it is"...etc. So the character knows something (for sure) because of some recent events and facts.

Answer (score 4):

Another example of ways of using つもり：

1. 天気についてはよく分かっている。だから明日は雪が降ると彼女に言うつもりだ。
   I know about weather very well (so I can tell it will snow tomorrow), and I intend to tell her about it.
2. 天気についてはよく分かっているつもりだ。だから明日は雪が降ると彼女に言う。
   I am confident that I know about weather well enough (so I can tell it will snow tomorrow), and I will tell her about it.

I hope this can help you as well.

Answer (score 3):

To the gentlemen above - it won't let me leave a comment because rep is too low, but...

My understanding is that 思う　means 'to think', where as つもり means 'to intend'.　So, you could say

りんごのほうがすしよりおいしいとおもいます。

= I think that apples are more delicious than sushi.

(my japanese is a little rough now actually.. somebody feel free to correct the grammar there.)

Comment: ok, but つもり has lots of different meanings depending on context. I think sawa's answer is not correct comparing it to "I think"

Answer (score 1):

As repecmps said, つもり can also indicate conviction or belief.  So in your example, 分かっているつもりだ means "I think I understand (but I could be wrong, or my understanding could be incomplete)," rather than "I intend to be in the know."

Comment: I personally think the idea of incertitude that everyone is referring to, is coming from a confusion with the main meaning of つもり (intend) when IMO, both meanings are independent. I believe "I think" and incertitude don't have their place here.