# Use of にだってある程度 in this sentence

Tags: usage

> もう何日も一緒に生活している俺と可憐。
>
> 当然すべてではないにしろ、俺**にだってある**程度今の可憐の気持ちはわかっているつもりだ。

I added the previous line for context.　 I made this  [だって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50294/clarifications-on-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-and-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-contractions) question a while back but it  may not apply to this instance.

Naturally, even if all of it (何日も一緒に生活している俺と可憐) wasn't there, even with my degree of (???), I think I understand Karen's feelings.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

俺にだって and ある程度 are two different phrases that adverbially modify 分かっている.

- 俺にだって is "even I (understand)" or "also I (understand)". だって itself is the same as the one you linked. This に is a particle used with わかる. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24955/5010).
- ある程度 is a very common set phrase, "to a certain degree", "to some extent", "more or less". See [this](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E7%A8%8B%E5%BA%A6&ref=sa).

> 当然すべてではないにしろ、俺にだってある程度今の可憐の気持ちはわかっているつもりだ。
>   I believe (even) I understand some of Karen's current feelings, if not all (of course).

Comment: 「~つもりだ」という表現は、「と思う」ぐらいという意味もあるなんですか？

Comment: @Rightleg Yes. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1822